# Add reaction of custom emoji to a message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

What can I tweak in my code that will allow me to use custom emojis to react to a message?

I have tried this:

```
 let suggestions = message.guild.channels.find("name", "suggestions");
  if (message.channel === suggestions) {
    message.channel.send().then(newMessage => {
       newMessage.react('<:information :412438127148531723>')
   })
  }
```

But I receive the error:

> **emoji_id: Value "412438127148531723>" is not snowflake.**

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** I didn't notice that you were trying to send an empty message via `.send()`, doing this will throw an error. Check @Blundering Philosopher's answer.

As the error states `emoji_id: Value "412438127148531723>" is not snowflake.`, that is indicated that you tried to pass something through the `.react()` that wasn't a snowflake which you have:

```
 newMessage('<:information :412438127148531723>') //here
```

As the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji?scrollTo=id) state the `Emoji`'s `id` is a type of [snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake).

So, you need to pass the `Emoji`'s `id` through the `.react();`, so simply replace this line: `newMessage.react('<:information :412438127148531723>')`, with this: `newMessage.react('412438127148531723')`

So your code should look like this as a result:

```
 let suggestions = message.guild.channels.find("name", "suggestions");
  if (message.channel === suggestions) {
    message.channel.send('your message').then(newMessage => {
       newMessage.react('412438127148531723')
   })
  }
```

Also, keep in mind that this will only work if the bot itself has access to the emoji, i.e - shares a server that has these emojis; the same way that Discord Nitro works.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot use `.send()` without any string or [`StringResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/StringResolvable) in the parenthesis. Try sending a basic string like this:

```
message.channel.send('Test message!').then(...)
```

Second, as @newbie mentioned, you shouldn't put `'<:information... :>'` around the emoji id, just do this:

```
// enter your emoji id inside the quotes
newMessage.react('...');
```

Finally, you should add `.catch` statements to any Discord function that returns a promise (like `.send` or `.react`) like this:

```
message.channel.send(...).then(...)
    .catch(console.error);

// and later in your code...
newMessage.react(...)
    .catch(console.error);
```

So to put all of your code together, do this:

```
let suggestions = message.guild.channels.find("name", "suggestions");
if (message.channel === suggestions) {
    // (send some text to channel)
    message.channel.send('Test message!').then(newMessage => {
        // (add your emoji id inside quotes -> probably '412438127148531723'
        newMessage.react('...')
        // (catch errors)
        .catch(console.error);
    })
    // (catch errors)
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the only response when you search this problem on google i'll answer it even if its 1 year old.

> **emoji_id: Value "412438127148531723>" is not snowflake.**

Just remove the > in the end so it is

```
newMessage.react('<:information :412438127148531723')
```

Worked for me. Hope it helps if someone is googling the same problem