# How To Make Discord Bot React Emoji To Specific Message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make Discord bot react emoji to certain message given by message id

If message id is '4778966219929685641' then if I try to message 
!react :emoji: 4778966219929685641
Then it should react in to the post.

I could not came up with the code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can find a similar question with an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759006/add-reaction-of-custom-emoji-to-a-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first things first is that you need to get the channel object, Lets say that we have the command in the message listener, Now next we will need to **fetch the message** (as shown in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage)), In the docs it says that we need to get the message ID, Assuming that you have arguments in the command, We will use a .then (or callback)

```
.then(message => {
```

It will react to the message the user wants to react the message with. So it should look like this

```
channel.fetchMessage("4778966219929685641").then(message => {
    message.react(argument[0]) //This is assuming that you are splitting the message content into an array, So it will get the first element.
})
```

If there is an error I made in this answer, reply to this answer and I will fix it.